# Ubuntu: how to kill a process that changes its PID?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm writing this command:

```
$ ps -aux | grep elasticsearch
```

and run it many times.

every time I get a different PID. I understand that PID changes. I want to kill this process. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
$ pkill elasticsearch
```

and

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't kill the process. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe it was transient process. is there an entry in `/proc` for this PID?

Comment: This sounds more like your ES is out of control rather than it changing the PID. It likely crashes on startup and the supervisor immediately restarts it. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Did my updated answer work?

Comment: If the process you are looking for exists you will have at least 2 rows in the result. If there is only one row the process you are looking for is not running. You will always get at least one row which in this case will be for the *grep elasticsearch* command.

Answer (score 1):

The first column is the process id. The process you are looking for is not running. The only reason grep has a result is because it's your command.

```
$ ps -aux | grep 73646 # starts grep process on process id 73656 in this example

***     73656  0.0  0.0  16272   948 pts/6    S+   01:29   0:00 grep --color=auto 73646 # the reason you have a match is because the last column is showing the command it started from.

$ kill -9 73664 # you are killing something which does not exist.
bash: kill: (73664) - No such process
```

Try the following and hopefully you will understand it:

```
$ ps -aux | grep elasticsearch

***     XXXXX  0.0  0.0  16272   948 pts/6    S+   01:29   0:00 grep --color=auto elasticsearch

$ kill -9 elasticsearch
bash: kill: (elasticsearch) - No such process
```

**EDIT:**
Try

```
pkill -f elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type in it: you wrote 73664 instead of 73646. Or did you mean 73656?